# Why my datatable Fixed header doesn`t work /

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am trying to make my data table Thead a sticky one but when i tried fixed header than it doesn't work . I have tried `position: fixed; , top: 0;`  and try to fix it with css but when a done this action than it works in firefox as expected but it doesn't work as expected in crome edge opera  .

```
    "stateSave": false,
    "orderCellsTop": true,
    "fixedHeader": {
        header: true,
    },
    "columns": [
    {'data':'chk_select_header','orderable': false},
```

Here is my code  of ajax .

Comment: Did you include the fixedHeader.js and fixedHeader.css files on your HTML page? https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/simple.html

Comment: Yes I did but it is still not working

Comment: I want my html body fixed and when i scroll table body down i want my thead as in sticky position . This option may Fix the table header to the top of a scrolling window but i wanted it in the top of table

Comment: I want to make my datatable look like this without using this plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Fix-Table-header-When-Scrolling-floatThead/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had tried to fixed my thead here in my data table . But this data table fixed that thead to the top of there page like this https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/simple.html but i wanted to make sticky to that data table div . i found only way to do it is using this below CSS method

```css
thead tr:first-child th {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 12;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

Or

```css
thead th {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 12;
    top: 51px;
    background: white;
}
```

This is the simplest method to sticky your data table header to the table head

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i learned something abouth sticky position. It works great, the only problem is that there is no stuck event when the thead sticks.

Answer (score 0):

**FixedHeader**, a datatables extension, can either be:

- downloaded in bundle [here](https://datatables.net/download/):  in download builder; or
- it can be included on your page as individual files ref. [here](https://datatables.net/download/release).
  Files for FixedHeader : [CSS](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.8/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css), [JS](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.8/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js)

This functionality is inbuilt in the extension, nothing separate needs to be done with CSS etc.
Here is how it is initialized:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true
} );
```

Or, after datatable has been constructed, it can be added using `new` keyword with the `$.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader` function:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table, {
    // more options
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add headeroffset
fixedHeader: {
header: true,
headerOffset: $('#navbar').height()
}
or

```
fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        headerOffset: 120
    }
```

this will be enough

docs: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/offset.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).